# Mathematical Induction problem...really need help

Tags: induction, arithmetic

> Prove with induction that $$3\cdot 4 + 5 \cdot7 + 7 \cdot 10 + 9\cdot 13 +\ldots+ (2n + 1)(3n + 1) = \frac{n}{2} \left(4n^2 + 11n + 9 \right)$$

*For n = 1

$(2n + 1)(3n + 1) = n/2 (4n^2 + 11n + 9)$
$(2*1 + 1)(3*1 + 1) = 1/2 (4(1) + 11 + 9)$
$12 = 12$ (proved)

*For n = k

$3*4 + 5*7 + 7*10 + 9*13 +...+ (2k + 1)(3k + 1) = k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9)$

*For $n = k + 1$

$3*4 + 5*7 + 7*10 + 9*13 +...+ (2k + 1)(3k + 1) + (2(k + 1) + 1)(3(k + 1) + 1) = (k + 1)/2 (4(k + 1)^2 + 11(k + 1) + 9)$

RHS:

$(k + 1)/2 (4(k + 1)^2 + 11(k + 1) + 9)$

Here's my working:

$3*4 + 5*7 + 7*10 + 9*13 +...+ (2k + 1)(3k + 1) + (2(k + 1) + 1)(3(k + 1) + 1) = (k + 2)/2 (4(k + 1)^2 + 11(k + 1) + 9)$

Since $3*4 + 5*7 + 7*10 + 9*13 +...+ (2k + 1)(3k + 1) = k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9)$, so

$k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9) + (2k + 3)(3k + 4) = (k + 1)/2 (4(k + 1)^2 + 11(k + 1) + 9)$

LHS:

$k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9) + (2k + 3)(3k + 4)$

$k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9) + (6k^2 + 17k + 12)$

$k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9) + k/2(12k + 34 + 24/k)$

$k/2 (4k^2 + 11k + 9 + 12k + 34 + 24/k)$

$k/2 (4k^2 + 23k + 43 + 24/k)$

Now I'm stucked. Can't solve LHS = RHS.
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use mathjax for readability.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea but taking out the factor of $\frac{k}{2}$ was misguided since you know that it's actually a factor of $\frac{k+1}{2}$ which is required.

There's nothing for it but to simply multiply out:-

$\frac{k}{2}(4k^2+11k+9)+(2k+3)(3k+4)=\frac{1}{2}(4k^3+23k^2+43k+24)=\frac{1}{2}(k+1)(4k^2+19k+24)$

And you're there.

Comment: Aww...thank you so much!